# laravel mysql ignore letters after number

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 .
I made my route rule. "/post/{id}"
and post will return with this code.

```
Post::find($id);
```

Yeah! It works.

But I just wondered whether it works with non-numeric or not. (ex : `1dssadf`) So I motified the code.

```
Post::find('1dssadf');
```

(There is a post id 1)

I excepted error. But It works. it found a post id 1. (ignored `dssadf`)

Why '1dssadf' treated as '1'?

Comment: If it is expecting a numeric the relevant conversion will take place automatically. This is pretty standard for most (?) languages I have used (or will be a compiler/interpreter option), I have always assumed it is allowed so that units and the like (eg 10km, 15%, 12oz) work without altering the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an id, so it is converted to what's relevant.

You can test with

```
echo (int) "1dssadf";
```

=> 1

MySQL equivalent :

```
SELECT CAST( '1dssadf' AS UNSIGNED )
```

=> 1

Comment: This happens in `mySql` not in `Laravel`.

Comment: It was en example to make him understand. I amended to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking, accepted answer is "not full".It's obviously that converting occurs - if it works and returns some result. Actually, Eloquent doesn't convert passed value from string to int. You can see at `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php` next:

```
/**
 * Find a model by its primary key.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $id
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|null
 */
public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    if (is_array($id)) {
        return $this->findMany($id, $columns);
    }

    $this->query->where($this->model->getQualifiedKeyName(), '=', $id);
    return $this->first($columns);
}
```

Builder just adds where-condition with name of current primary key. Then it ( builder ) compiles all params/conditions/etc. to prepared statement and excetutes it. In your case it will be `select * from posts where posts.id = ? limit 1` with `$bindings` array `[0 => "1dssadf"]`.You can see this moment at `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php` ( method `select`). And finally, answer is that MySQL recognises that id should be an integer (INT), and automatically convert the string "1dssadf" to the integer 1 (inbuilt behaviour), without any `(int)...` or `CAST(..)`.